# How to call php file using function/method?

Tags: php

Normally we execute php file by calling file_name.php from url, Instead of calling file_name from url can i call method/function from url to execute php file? If yes,please explain me with example.

Comment: Yeah, why not allow anyone execute any code on your server?!

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360182/call-php-function-from-url ?

Comment: You can execute anything you want? What are you asking? Are you looking for a router?

Comment: Please try to explain your problem in a clearer way. How are we supposed to know what you are talking about?

Comment: my question is , we type the file_name.php in url but is that possible to call that file using method instead of calling its name.ext?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's unclear what you are asking for.

I think you want `curl`. Curl call will execute php script on your server.

Or you can execute code from a server with commands like `php script.php`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly: you wont to execute the content of anoder *.php file from widhin a php file.

just use "include":

```
include('path/to/my/file.php');
```

[Look the definition for "include" here in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Hope ite helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use exec() php function.
 see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

and to execute php file you can try this way.

```
exec('php path/to/your/phpfile.php');
```

for example:

```
exec('php /var/www/proj/home.php');
```

if your php file return something and you want to save it in variable then tyr this

```
exec('php /var/www/proj/home.php',$var);
```

if you want to call home.php from index.php then your index.php will look like

**index.php**

```
<?php
exec('php /var/www/proj/home.php');
?>
```