# Securely instantiate PHP class from URL get parameter?

Tags: php, security, parameters, templating

I've written a little code-snippet that should instantiate a php class based on a get-parameter.

(Code edited based on the suggestions from @sietse85 and @CBroe:)

```
  $this->pageVal = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page')) ? preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page')) : "index";

  $file = $this->moduleDir . $this->pageVal . ".php";
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    require_once $file;
    $class = new $this->pageVal($this);
  } else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    $this->loadPage("404");
  }
```

In this similar question is warned to do something like this:
[Call PHP function from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360182/call-php-function-from-url)

In other questions people sometimes get warned when they use unsecure code - now I *tried* to remove **some** security issues (in my code) based on these warnings by using filter_input and requiere only files that exist. Perhaps this is not enough or not the right procedure?

**Should I whitelist existing pages and possible parameters too or do something else to avoid security issues or would this not be necessary?**

Like this:

```
$existingPages = ["index", "profile", "login", "register"];

if(in_array(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page'), $existingPages)) {

  //GO ON WITH PROCESSING
  $this->pageVal = filter_input(...)

}
```

If the background of my question is not clear *from your point of view* please describe the problem to help me to specify it.

Thank you!

Comment: Seeing as it looks like you did not currently take into account even essential basics such as a path traversal attack, I think _you_ should probably rather go with a whitelist ...

Comment: make sure you remove dots and slashes from this get parameter. Actually try to only allow A-Za-z `$this->pageVal = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $this->pageVal);`

Comment: So I would use this?:
`$this->pageVal = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page')) ? preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page')) : "index";`

Sorry this is horrific to read here - maybe paste it in a textfile to read it? I combined it with the ternary oparation.

Comment: If you are asking about security, it's a clear sign you should keep out of this topic. Don't reinvent the wheel, there are lots of [routers out there](https://packagist.org/?q=router) already.

Comment: Thank you for your rating of my question and constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to remove security issues (in my code) based on these warnings by using filter_input

Sorry - you didn't remove the security issues, this code is still vulnerable to directory traversal. The `filter_input()` function is IMHO a *very* inappropriate function. You should never change the representation of input but you should validate it. However filter_input() needs to be told *how* you want to validate it. And it doesn't have an option for a partial filename.

> Should I whitelist existing pages

If you fix the directory traversal issue, then you have whitelisted the scripts which can be run - it will only be possible to run scripts in the designated directory.

Consider:

```
$this->pageVal = basename($_GET['file']);
$file = $this->moduleDir . $this->pageVal . ".php";
if (!is_readable($file)) {
    trigger_warning("User attempted to access non-existent code: " 
      . base64encode($_GET['page']), E_USER_WARNING);
    $this->pageVal = 'index';
    $file = $this->moduleDir . $this->pageVal . ".php";
}
require_once $file;
```

Using a regex to remove/retain arbitrary characters is not an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful for me. Digging a bit deeper in this topic I  read about "basename()" and "realpath()". What about combining them to `$this->pageVal = basename(realpath($_GET['page']));` to strip directory information and get the full path?

Comment: No - because if you let the user specify the directory then you've got directory traversal again & lose your whitelist.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will have to go deeper into this topic. Your answer shows me that I am maybe a bit far away from an acceptable solution.