# Redirect to another URL writing it inside the own URL

Tags: php, url

Very probably this is impossible, but I want to ask it, just in case.

I have a database in which I save some numbers (1, 2, 3...).

I have a `.php` page from which I read the numbers.  I concat those numbers to a string for getting a full URL.  For exmaple:

```
$intArticle = $row["article"];
$strURLBase = "example.com/index.php/"
$strLink = $strURLBase . $intArticle;

//And I get "example.com/index.php/1"
```

But now, there is an exception in which the URL points to an external website, so my code is not valid for now.

I know how to fix it in `.php`, but I would like to know if it is possible to make the redirect directly inside the URL, saving the properly string inside the database.  For example:

```
$intArticle = $row["article"];  //In this case, the value of $row["article"] could be, for example, "http://www.externalweb.com"
$strURLBase = "example.com/index.php/"  //This part should be ignore inside the URL
$strLink = $strURLBase . $intArticle;

//I would get "example.com/index.php/http://www.externalweb.com"
```

Is there any kind of instruction that I could write inside the URL (that I would save into the database and then I would concat to `$strURLBase`) that redirects to another URL?  For example:

```
example.com/index.php/!$%&_redirec_to("http://www.externalweb.com")
```

I don't want to call any PHP function from the URL for the redirection.  In fact any PHP code shouldn't be executed.  Everything should be inside the URL.

Comment: I guess while concatenation you could check whats there in the intArticle variable. If there is url then use the url itself. If its just a number use your string instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call PHP function from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360182/call-php-function-from-url)

Comment: That script for executing PHP code from the URL is really interesting, but as I have edited in my post, any PHP code shouldn't be executed.  Everything should be inside the URL.  I'm just asking if it is possible to do or not what I am asking, but it seems that it is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!is_numeric($intArticle))
{
header("Location: ".$strLink."");
exit;
}
// your site will continue here, if the article is a number
```

Comment: As I said, I know how to do it in php.  I asked if it is possible to do it inside the own URL.

Comment: You could probably use $_GET.

Comment: `$_GET` would be use inside php, not inside the URL, so it is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Hmm, yea sorry for that, maybe then use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and str_pos()

Comment: Again, that's not valid...  That's is code that I would have to write inside php!  One more time, I explain that the function should be inside the URL, in the place that I indicate in this picture:  http://res.cloudinary.com/saintseiya/image/upload/v1537012974/1_ivgk6u.jpg